# 245mm tire on 7.5 inch rim?

Tags: tires, car, wheels, wheel-balance, front-wheel-drive

I am looking to buy snow tires. I saw an ad for someone selling 4 Michelin Latitude X-ICE X12 tires mounted with wheels. Size is 245/65R17. Wheels are 17X7.5 Sport Edition P5 Anthracite. He claims that he drove on them for one season and is moving down south so he no longer needs them. Tread is 9/32 of an inch and looks fairly new from pics.

From what I've read, the tire tire will fit my car but I've seen that the 245mm tire is slightly oversized for the 7.5 inch rim. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Michelin website,

[Latitude X-Ice Xi2](https://www.michelinman.com/tires/x-ice/latitude-xice-xi2.html) - 245/65R17 107T

Rim Width Range (Min - Max) 7.00" - 8.50"

so yes, they will work on your 7.5 inch wide rims.

Comment: Thanks! Didnt think to check manufacturers website.

Comment: Always check the manufacturer data as the allowable wheel width for a tire may be different down to the tire model level.  There's some general "good fitment" ranges, but ultimately if you are pushing the boundaries of those, the manufacturer is the place to check!